# LINQ to SQL, DataContext issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

While using LINQ to SQL, I created a static DataContext in my custom class i.e.

```
public class OPIS
 {
 public static DataContext DataContext = new DataContext();
 ....
}
```

Now whenever i need to query (including insert and delete) results via LINQ i use this static DataContext object. I never figured out a problem until I was unable to get the the recently inserted object in one of the EntitySet e.g.

I have a `Profile` and a `BasicInfo` EntityType with one-to-one relationship with eachother.

```
//Inserting a new BasicInfo Object, have created association with Profile object before
OPIS.DataContext.BasicInfos.InsertOnSubmit(basicInfoObject);
```

Now on another page

```
Profile profile = //get new profile from linq, comming fine

BasicInfo bi = profile.BasicInfo //returning null, it shouldn't
```

`bi` should return an object of associated BasicInfo with profile, but it is not. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you ever calling `SubmitChanges()` on your `DataContext`?  If not, then all you are doing is registering the `BasicInfo` for insertion, but never inserting it.

```
OPIS.DataContext.BasicInfos.InsertOnSubmit(basicInfoObject); //registers object for insertion
OPIS.DataContext.SubmitChanges(); // performs insert
```

Comment: @Sadi - did you have any luck determining what was causing your issue?